# Check and uncheck of checkboxes

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have three division and each division contain 3 checkboxes.

```html
<div class="options">
  <div class="offers">
    <form action="">
      <div class="multiselect">
        <div class="selectBox click">
          <select class="select">
            <option>Select an option</option>
          </select>
          <div class="overSelect"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="open" class="box">
          <input type="checkbox" id="one" />
          <label for="one" class="i">First checkbox</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="two" />
          <label for="two">Second checkbox </label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="three" />
          <label for="three">Third checkbox</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="offers">
    <form action="">
      <div class="multiselect">
        <div class="selectBox click">
          <select class="select">
            <option>Select an option</option>
          </select>
          <div class="overSelect"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="open" class="box">
          <label for="one">
            <input type="checkbox" id="one" />First checkbox</label>
          <label for="two">
            <input type="checkbox" id="two" />Second checkbox </label>
          <label for="three">
            <input type="checkbox" id="three" />Third checkbox</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="offers">
    <form action="">
      <div class="multiselect">
        <div class="selectBox click">
          <select class="select">
            <option>Select an option</option>
          </select>
          <div class="overSelect"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="open" class="box">
          <label for="one">
            <input type="checkbox" id="one" />First checkbox</label>
          <label for="two">
            <input type="checkbox" id="two" />Second checkbox </label>
          <label for="three">
            <input type="checkbox" id="three" />Third checkbox</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have used label so that if i click on label checkbox get check.
But its happening only in first div and in other div if click on label changes occur in first div. And also if i click on label on other div other than first checkbox are not checking

Comment: You must give unique id for each input so you can set the correct for value in the label tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the issue is you do not have unique `ids` in your page. Element `id` should be unique to every element.

Change the duplicate `ids` and accordingly change the `for` attribute of `label` tag.

Here is your new code:

```html
<div class="options">
  <div class="offers">
    <form action="">
      <div class="multiselect">
        <div class="selectBox click">
          <select class="select">
            <option>Select an option</option>
          </select>
          <div class="overSelect"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="open" class="box">
          <input type="checkbox" id="one_1" />
          <label for="one_1" class="i">First checkbox</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="two_1" />
          <label for="two_1">Second checkbox</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="three_1" />
          <label for="three_1">Third checkbox</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="offers">
    <form action="">
      <div class="multiselect">
        <div class="selectBox click">
          <select class="select">
            <option>Select an option</option>
          </select>
          <div class="overSelect"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="open" class="box">
          <label for="one_2">
            <input type="checkbox" id="one_2" />First checkbox</label>
          <label for="two_2">
            <input type="checkbox" id="two_2" />Second checkbox</label>
          <label for="three_2">
            <input type="checkbox" id="three_2" />Third checkbox</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="offers">
    <form action="">
      <div class="multiselect">
        <div class="selectBox click">
          <select class="select">
            <option>Select an option</option>
          </select>
          <div class="overSelect"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="open" class="box">
          <label for="one_3">
            <input type="checkbox" id="one_3" />First checkbox</label>
          <label for="two_3">
            <input type="checkbox" id="two_3" />Second checkbox</label>
          <label for="three_3">
            <input type="checkbox" id="three_3" />Third checkbox</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When i am running this snippet it is working fine, whenever i am clicking on any label the corresponding checkbox is selected.

Comment: does it have to do with my jquery for slideup and slidedown?

Comment: When you click on `run code snippet`, you seeing the problem solved?

Comment: it works...what is issue? but **id's should be unique per page**...above code has still same id on each row element, but not effecting the functionality...

Comment: Probably you rest of the code has multiple `ids` as well. Or try the update code.

Comment: $(function(){
   var sp=0;
   var sd;
   $(".click").click(function(){
    if(sp==0)
    {
     sp=1;
     
     sd=$(this).siblings("#open");
     $(this).siblings("#open").slideDown();
    }
    else
    {
     
     sd.slideUp();
     if(sd[0]!=$(this).siblings("#open")[0])
      {
       
       $(this).siblings("#open").slideDown();
      }
     else{
      
      sp=0;
      $(this).siblings("#open").slideUp();
     }
     sd=$(this).siblings("#open");

    }


   });
   
  });

Comment: jquery for slide up and slide down

Comment: This won't create any issue.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="options">
  <div class="offers">
    <form action="">
      <div class="multiselect">
        <div class="selectBox click">
          <select class="select">
            <option>Select an option</option>
          </select>
          <div class="overSelect"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="open1" class="box">
          <input type="checkbox" id="one" />
          <label for="one" class="i">First checkbox</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="two" />
          <label for="two">Second checkbox</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="three" />
          <label for="three">Third checkbox</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="offers">
    <form action="">
      <div class="multiselect">
        <div class="selectBox click">
          <select class="select">
            <option>Select an option</option>
          </select>
          <div class="overSelect"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="open2" class="box">
          <label for="one_2">
            <input type="checkbox" id="one_2" />First checkbox</label>
          <label for="two_2">
            <input type="checkbox" id="two_2" />Second checkbox</label>
          <label for="three_2">
            <input type="checkbox" id="three_2" />Third checkbox</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="offers">
    <form action="">
      <div class="multiselect">
        <div class="selectBox click">
          <select class="select">
            <option>Select an option</option>
          </select>
          <div class="overSelect"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="open3" class="box">
          <label for="one_3">
            <input type="checkbox" id="one_3" />First checkbox</label>
          <label for="two_3">
            <input type="checkbox" id="two_3" />Second checkbox</label>
          <label for="three_3">
            <input type="checkbox" id="three_3" />Third checkbox</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```